# How to get the JUnit surefire report programatically

Tags: maven, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, junit-runner

I need to use `JUnitCore` to run unit tests from a standalone jar test tool. I have added the surefire jars as dependencies and there I found the class `org.apache.maven.surefire.junitcore.JUnitCoreRunListener`. [In this github](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/surefire-providers/surefire-junit47/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/surefire/junitcore/JUnitCoreRunListenerTest.java) this is a sample of its usage.

My intention is to get the xml report that would result from running maven without maven at runtime.

```
RunListener reporter = new JUnitCoreRunListener( new MockReporter(), new HashMap<String, TestSet>() );
JUnitCore jc = new JUnitCore();
jc.addListener( reporter );
Result r = jc.run( new Computer(), AppTest.class);
jc.removeListener( reporter );
System.out.println( r );
```

This is not working. What is the correct approach to get the XML output from that reporter?